# How to access koa context in another generator function?

Tags: node.js, koa

In Koa I can accesss a Koa Context in the first generator function via `this`:

```
app.use(function *(){
    this; // is the Context
}
```

But if I yield to another generator function I can't access the context via `this` anymore.

```
app.use(function *(){
    yield myGenerator();
}

function* myGenerator() {
    this.request; // is undefined
}
```

I've been able to simply pass the context to the second generator function, but was wondering whether there's a cleaner way to access the context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either pass `this` as an argument as you said:

```
app.use(function *(){
    yield myGenerator(this);
});

function *myGenerator(context) {
    context.request;
}
```

or use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
app.use(function *(){
    yield myGenerator.apply(this);
});

function *myGenerator() {
    this.request;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Cheers Vinicius!

Comment: What if my generator function has other arguments I want to pass in?